# Creating a function where I can input first names and last names into a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am kind of stuck, I am trying to make a function that allows me to append onto an empty dict, I want to add first name and surname, and also make it possible to have people with same last names but different first names. Any ideas? This is my first time asking a question on here, let me know if I need to find any other info thanks!

```py
def people():
    people = {}
    prompt = input("Would you like to add a person to the list? (Y/N): ")
    while prompt.lower() == "y":
        qs = dict(name='first name', surname='last name')
        for key, value in qs.items():
            people[key] = input('Please enter your {}: '.format(value))
            print(people)
        prompt = input("Another person? (Y/N): ")
    print(people)
    return people


people()
```

Comment: Why are you using a `dict` for storing `people`? The idea to form a dynamic dialog on the console by using a dict looks really nice (and expandable to data as age, middle name etc), but the way you store the input is definitively wrong (because you are actually destroying user data). A dict is for accessing data by a unique key. You need to build such a key yourself, this is what Hridaya Agrawal's answer (2nd part) is about. If you don't have an idea how to get such a unique key, think about adding tuples, i.e. `(forename, surname)`, to a *`list`* instead.

Answer (score 1):

First ask the user the `input('Please enter your {}: '.format(value))`

store it in a variable and then assign the people[key] to the variable

Example:

```
def people():
    people = {}
    prompt = input("Would you like to add a person to the list? (Y/N): ")
    while prompt.lower() == "y":
        qs = dict(name='first name', surname='last name')
        for key, value in qs.items():
            name = input('Please enter your {}: '.format(value))
            people[key] = name
            print(people)
        prompt = input("Another person? (Y/N): ")
    print(people)
    return people
```

As mentioned in the comments that the people dicts gets reset

So with the approach of nested dicts you can use this:

```
def people():
people_ = {}
prompt = input("Would you like to add a person to the list? (Y/N): ")
while prompt.lower() == "y":
    qs = dict(name='first name', surname='last name')
    print(qs)
    index = f"person_{len(people_) + 1}"
    people_[index] = {}
    for key, value in qs.items():
        name = input('Please enter your {}: '.format(value))
        people_[index][key] = name
        print(people_)
    prompt = input("Another person? (Y/N): ")
print(people_)
return people_
```

Comment: When I did this, only the most recent input gets return, the others seem to not get stored, do I need to use append method somewhere

Comment: What do you mean? `prompt = input("Another person? (Y/N): ")` you mean when this is called and user inputs Y then it gets reset?

Comment: Yep, Got it now, So you should use nested dicts inside the people dict

Comment: Please enter your first name: Jose
{'name': 'Jose', 'surname': 'Jones'}
Please enter your last name: Hernandez
{'name': 'Jose', 'surname': 'Hernandez'}
Another person? (Y/N): y
Please enter your first name: George
{'name': 'George', 'surname': 'Hernandez'}
Please enter your last name: Jeffries
{'name': 'George', 'surname': 'Jeffries'}
Another person? (Y/N): n
{'name': 'George', 'surname': 'Jeffries'}

Comment: Ok I will give that a try.

Comment: @RileyIttidecharchoti I have added the solution for nested dicts, and should work now!

Answer (score 1):

```
def people():
    people = {}
    add_person_msg = "Add person to list? (Y/N): "
    first_name_msg = "First name: "
    last_name_msg = "Last name: "

    while input(add_person_msg).lower() == 'y':     #.lower()
        people[input(first_name_msg)] = input(last_name_msg)

    return people

print(people())
```

if you wanted to work with the names before storing in dictionary, for example capitalize them:

```
def people_dict():
    fn_msg = "First name: "
    ln_msg = "Last name: "
    people = {} 
    while input("Add person? y/n: ").lower() == 'y':
        fn, ln = input(fn_msg).title(), input(ln_msg).title()
        people[fn] = ln 
    return people
```

Also instead of using `.format()` method,

```
input('Please enter your {}: '.format(value)
```

if you are using Python 3.5 and above you can use [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/):

```
input(f'Please enter your {value}:')
```

Comment: This does make it a lot simpler! However, I am getting the issue in which the printed out dict is just the last entry of name and last name I  inputed